# Artifacts in all meshes, even when creating a new project and adding a basic cube

Tags: normals, artifacts

so Ihave that problem that all my meshes are broken so I have artifacts everywhere, especially around edges. You can see that all face orientations are messed up and recalcualting outsides doesn`t work. This even happened when I was creating a completly new object. Obviously the artifacts become stronger when scaling the object to larger sizes.

When im changing from Layout mode to UV Editing, the artifacts are not appearing. I am currently working on Blender 3.3.1? Can any one help me with my problem?
[image]
[image]

Greetings
Dominik

Comment: Hello, maybe a Clipping issue, open the N panel > View > tweak the Clip Start and End values

Comment: Your View clip-range is huge, at the moment.. bring the near-far range into something proportionate to your model's dimensikons (BTW, probably Ctrl-A apply the scale of your object, if you're in the modelling phase of your project)

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast response! It was actually the View clip-range. Adjusting the clip start to 5 m worked.